# Why is my C program printing 0.000000 here?

Tags: c, floating-point

I just started to learn C programming.
In my book there is this piece of code:

```
/*Code Start*/
/*This code is use to find the simple interest*/

main ()
{
int p, n;
float r, si;

p = 1000;
n = 3;
r = 8.5;

si= p*n*r/100;
printf("%f", si);

}

/*Code end*/
```

The output i got was " 255.000000 "

I though i'll modify it with scanf function so i wrote this:

```
/*Code Start*/

main ()
{
int p, n;
float r, si;

printf("Enter value for p: \n");
scanf("%d", &p);
printf("Enter value for n: \n\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("Enter valuse for r: \n\n");
scanf("%d", &r);

si= p*n*r/100;

printf("\nYour Simple Interest is %f\n\n", si);
}

/*Code End*/
```

No matter what values i give to p,n,r the answer i get is always 0.000000..
I also tried giving the values, p=1000, n=3, r=8.5 but still i get 0.000000..

Comment: Just remember this: `%d` for `int` ,`%f` for `float` ,`%e` for `double` ,`%c` for `char` , `%s` for strings.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall`. By enabling the warnings, you will be able to pinpoint the four problems with this code. The fixes you need to apply are obvious from the warning messages.

Comment: Your book has `main` without a prototype, that is doesn't specify a return value and has an empty parameter list? This looks quite outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your main problem: The `%d` specifier is only for integers, **not** `float`s or `double`s. Use `%f` for `float`s.

In addition, the `main` should return an `int`, this will do:

```
int main() {
    /* your code */
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, I would recommend you make better use of white-space as it will vastly help with readability once you start making larger programs.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.
Can you please explain what did you mean by main should return an int ? What does this main() mean ? Why should we add int before it ? and what can we put in the parentheses ?

Comment: @912M0FR34K: The `main` function is the entry point for the program, called by the execution environment. The language specification requires `main` to return an `int` value. The two standard signatures for `main` are `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. Whenever you see `main()` in your book, replace it with `int main(void)`.  Out of curiousity, what book are you using?

Comment: @JhonBode: Thank you again. I am using "Programming in ANSI - E Balagurusamy" . If you think its not good, which book will you suggest ? I am new to programming

Comment: @John-Bode:Thank you again. I am using "Programming in ANSI - E Balagurusamy" . If you think its not good, which book will you suggest ? I am new to programming

Comment: Maybe some classic like B.Kernighan, D.Ritchie-,,The C Programming Language''?

Answer (score 6):

Change the specifier in `scanf`. You're using `%d` instead of `%f`:

```
scanf("%f", &r);
        ^
```

- First side note: the code looks kind of bad (no return type for `main` ?!). Are you sure it's a good book ?
- Second side note: using `float`s today is kind of pointless. Maybe you
  should use `double`s ?

Comment: There are some fields where `float` still makes sense, for example in graphics or games, often `double` precision is not required but `float` is way faster.

Comment: @ouah Yes, I think that's quite sensible. Still, I feel floats are being overused.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.
Can you please explain what did you mean by main should return an int ? What does this main() mean ? Why should we add int before it ? and what can we put in the parentheses ?
What book would you suggest for me to learn C ? i am a beginner and this is my first language.

Answer (score 4):

Use `%f` conversion specification to read a `float`:

```
scanf("%f", &r);
```

`%d` means it reads a decimal integer and not a `float`.

Answer (score 4):

`r` is a `float`, but you're reading it in using `%d` as a `scanf` specifier, which expects an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The real culprit in your code is the line `scanf("**%d**", &r)`.
`%d` is the format specifier for integer value, as you declared r as float then use `%f` instead of `%d`.

i.e. `scanf("%f", &r)`

Comment: Correct, but why rehash what the other 4 answers said 3 years later?

Answer (score 0):

Change Either
**int p, n;
float r, si;**
to 
**int p, n,r;
float si;**

or change formate specifier in **scanf("%d", &r)**; **%d** to **%f**.

when you declare r as an integer **r=8** will be considered, in that case scanf("%d", &r); will be accepted. and your program get compiled and executed.

both declaration and formate specifier should be same.

my suggestion is to use **%.2f** when dealing with money. which will give like 10.00 which is the correct formate.